# Oracle 11g partitioning by multiple fields - calculation method

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, partitioning

I need to know, when I use partition by range of 2 fields, e.g.

```
PARTITION BY RANGE ("STATUS","LASTMODIFIEDDATE")
```

So when I give a partition range of something like

```
PARTITION "OUTGBEN_DONE_20141118"  VALUES LESS THAN ('Done', TIMESTAMP' 2014-11-19 00:00:00')
```

How is this "less than" calculated when I insert a new record?
Is it simply concatenates the two fields from the inserted record as string and compare it alphabetically to the values I gave it?

Comment: Just like `ORDER BY Status,LASTMODIFIEDDATE`.. Which ever is greater.. Not alphabetical, But Based on the datatype itself.

Comment: I asked this because I've found that a single space that mistalenly was added to the end of the string, like ('Done ', TIMESTAMP' 2014-11-19 00:00:00') at the STATUS string, made all the records (which comes wihtout space after the 'Done') to be inserted to the lowest partition, although their timestamp was higher.